# Swift xcode: Changing the name/title of a row/cell inside a Table by a text input after pressing a button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Scroll down to the last method of the first class (MainProjectScene). The "PressedSaveAs" function is the method I'm trying to solve, and it's the same method with the error in the screenshot.

When the user presses the button, the text input will appear and when you click "okay" it will assign the text that the user has inputted to the title of the row/cell of the table.

Screenshot of error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy6LP.png)

Screenshot of text field I would like to assign to the title of the row/cell (this will happen when I press the button, so the functionality is inside the PressedSaveAs method):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4pBm.png)

```
import UIKit



weak var FirstFileNameTextField: UILabel!



class MainProjectScene: UIViewController

{



    var row: Row?



    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)

    {



        if let r = row

        {



            row!.FileName = r.FileName



            row!.QuartzImage = r.QuartzImage



        }

    }



    override func  viewDidLoad()

    {

        super.viewDidLoad()



        // FacebookButton.addTarget(self, action: "didTapFacebook", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)



    }



    @IBOutlet weak var NewFileButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var TwoDQuartzButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var YouTubeButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var TwitterButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var OpenFileButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var SnapChatButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var FacebookButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedTwoDQuartzButton(sender: UIButton) {



    }



    @IBAction func PressedSnapchatButton(sender: UIButton){



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.snapchat.com/")!)



    }



    @IBAction func PressedYouTubeButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/")!)



    }



    @IBOutlet weak var InstagramButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedFacebookButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.facebook.com")!)



    }

    @IBAction func PressedInstagramButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/")!)



    }



    @IBAction func PressedTwitterButton(sender: UIButton) {



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/")!)



    }



    @IBOutlet weak var SaveAsButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func PressedSaveAs(sender: UIButton) //this is the save as function that I would like to know how to change



    {



        //1. Create the alert controller.



        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name/rename your file:", message: "Enter a filename to name/rename and save your file", preferredStyle: .Alert)



        //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.



        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in



            textField.text = "Your file name"

        })



        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler:

            {

                (action) -> Void in

                let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

                print("Text field: \(textField.text)")

               // rows.cell.textLabel?.text = textField.text

                CurrentFileName = textField.text!

                rows[indexPath.row].FileName = CurrentFileName

        }))



        // 4. Present the alert.

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)





            // rows[indexPath.row].FileName = rows.cell.textLabel?.text



            // rows[i] = textField.text



    }





}
```

Row class

```
import UIKit





let rows = [

    Row(FileName: "File slot 1",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 1"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 2",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 2"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 3",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 3"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 4",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 4"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 5",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 5"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 6",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 6"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 7",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 7"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 8",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 8"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 9",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 9"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 10",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 10"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 11",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 11"),

    Row(FileName: "File slot 12",

        QuartzImage: "Image slot 12")]



//update contents of the array

//each of the table cell will use the stored information in the array

//



class Row

{

    ///// enum Type: String {

    // }



    var FileName: String

    var QuartzImage: String



    // var type: Type

    // var shortDescription: String

    // var longDescription: String



    init(FileName: String, QuartzImage: String) {

        self.FileName = FileName

        self.QuartzImage = QuartzImage



    }


}
```

RowTableViewController class

```
import UIKit



var CurrentIndex = 0

var CurrentFileName = ""



class RowTableViewController: UITableViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {



        super.viewDidLoad()



        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations



        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false



        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.



        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()



    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {



        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()



        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.



    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source



    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {



        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections



        return 1



    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows



        return rows.count



    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FileSlot", forIndexPath: indexPath)



        let filename = rows[indexPath.row].FileName



        print(filename)



        cell.textLabel?.text = filename



        return cell



    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

    {



        let title = "List of Files"

        let message = "You have selected \(rows[indexPath.row].FileName)"



        // CurrentIndex = rows[didSelectRowAtIndexPath.row]

        var i = 0

        CurrentIndex = indexPath.row

        CurrentFileName = rows[indexPath.row].FileName

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okayAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)



    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {



        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].



        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.



        if let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? MainProjectScene {



            if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {



                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {



                    detailViewController.row = rows[indexPath.row]



                }



            }



        }



        //   let index = RowTableViewController.indexPathForSelectedRow()



        //let currentCell = RowTableViewController.cellForRowAtIndexPath(RowTableViewController.indexPath) as UITableViewCell



        //println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)



    }



    /*



    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {



    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.



    return true



    }



    */



    /*



    // Override to support editing the table view.



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



    if editingStyle == .Delete {



    // Delete the row from the data source



    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)



    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {



    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view



    }



    }



    */



    /*



    // Override to support rearranging the table view.



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {



    }



    */



    /*



    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {



    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.



    return true

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the scope of indexPath is the problem, you would need to use

```
weakSelf.indexPath (if a class level variable)
```

This is due to the closure (or block) you are using having different scope than the rest of the code in your method.  The reason you would need to use weakSelf rather than simply "self." is to avoid a retain cycle, documentation explaining this can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID57)

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: Great, glad it was useful!